# Kentico UniPager in custom UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

In my aspx file I have the cms:UniView control, and cms:UniPager for it. This works fine. Now I want to move the cms:UniPager control to another place. I'm placing it into my custom UserControl and replace cms:UniPager in the aspx file by this custom control. But there is a problem. The cms:UniPager does not appear on the page. May be I forget about some important thing?

There is my code below:

My custom PagingControl.ascx.cs file

```
public string PageControl { get; set; }

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UniPager.PageControl = PageControl;
}
```

My custom PagingControl.ascx file

```
<cms:UniPager ID="UniPager" runat="server" GroupSize="3">
    <!--Some elements-->
</cms:UniPager>
```

My aspx file where I'm using it

```
<cms:UniView ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <!--Some data-->
</cms:UniView>

<PagingControlTagPrefix:PagingControl PageControl="Repeater1" runat="server"/>
```